# What is the feature called in Material UI, that when clicking on it makes a component appear without refreshing the page?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I am new to material UI and I want to design something like this. But I am unable to find the name of the feature that helps accomplish this.

[image]

When I click on option 1 I want to display its market summary without refreshing the rest of the components on the page. Is it just a button that helps accomplish this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to [vertical tabs](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tabs/#vertical-tabs). Without refreshing the page means, you have to hard-code your chart data or you need to call an [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) request to fetch data when the user switch to that tab (option 1).